# How to pass sfx settings to the SevenZipSfx class

Tags: c#, 7zip, sfx, sevenzipsharp

Does anyone know how to pass the sfx settings for the SevenZipSfx class located at http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/. I need to specify what file to run, etc. I just took one of the samples e.g

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
RunProgram="setup.exe /s"
GUIMode="2"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

and set it via the sfx.ModuleFileName property but its fails with null exception when I call the
sfx.MakeSfx(@"C:\a.7z", @"C:\test.exe"); inside the GetSettingsStream(...) as the settings.key is null

I don't think this is the correct way but can't seem to locate where its reading the settings from. I don't want to hard code this in the source.

Comment: I took another look at the code and the overloaded method:         public void MakeSfx(string archiveFileName, SfxSettings settings, string sfxFileName)

has the sfx setting being passed in via collection dictionary object. This is the exposed way of passing in the settings. I'll use it to pass in my settings when creating the sfx file.